# extracting name, email and number and save it into a variable

Tags: python, parsing, extract

I want to extract the name, email and phone number of all the conversations and then save them into different variables. I want to save it like this: a=max, b=email and so on.

This is my text file:

```
[11:23] max : Name : max

Email : max@gmail.com

Phone : 01716345678

[11:24] harvey : hello there how can i help you
[11:24] max : can you tell me about the latest feature
```

and this is my code. What am I missing here?

```
in_file = open("chat.txt", "rt")

contents = in_file.read()
#line: str
for line in in_file:
    if line.split('Name :'):
        a=line
        print(line)

    elif line.split('Email :'):
        b = line

    elif line.split('Phone :'):
        c = line


    else:
        d = line
```

Comment: What do you expect the output of `line.split()` to be?

Comment: `split` never returns an empty list, even if the separator is not found in the string. In this case it returns a list with the entire string as a single element, so `if line.split('Name :')` is always going to be `True` hence none of the `elif` blocks are being executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what `split` does, at all. You might be getting it confused with `in`.

In any case, a regular expression will do:

```
import re

string = '''[11:23] max : Name : max

Email : max@gmail.com

Phone : 01716345678

[11:24] harvey : hello there how can i help you
[11:24] max : can you tell me about the latest feature'''

keys = ['Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Text']
result = re.search('.+Name : (\w+).+Email : ([\w@\.]+).+Phone : (\d+)(.+)', string, flags=re.DOTALL).groups()

{key: data for key, data in zip(keys, result)}
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'max',
 'Email': 'max@gmail.com',
 'Phone': '01716345678',
 'Text': '\n\n[11:24] harvey : hello there how can i help you\n[11:24] max : can you tell me about the latest feature'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line in your code:
"contents = in_file.read()"

Also, use "in" instead of "split":

```
in_file = open("chat.txt", "rt")
for line in in_file:
    if ('Name') in line:
        a=line
        print(a)
    elif 'Email' in line:
        b = line
        print(b)
    elif 'Phone' in line:
        c = line
        print(c)
    else:
        d = line
        print(d)
```